# Looking for a decent small mic for video recording

Tags: microphones

I have [came across this video](https://youtu.be/kb7-mq-6MXM?t=11). The vLogger has a mic in his hand. The same can be seen in [his shirt neck in this another video](https://youtu.be/-5YG_lu0IGE)

I'm trying to order this from [Amazon in India but I cannot find it](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=collar%20mic%20for%20mobile&adgrpid=58361394185&ext_vrnc=hi&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyJn5BRDrARIsADZ9ykGqAmm9J248qIe7Nn6hU6PcHoPx_SQFcQnXoVF669hVuAFkQriDI_IaAuBIEALw_wcB&hvadid=398048338531&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9062209&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=12404205154276959212&hvtargid=kwd-431409553134&hydadcr=28681_1997824&tag=googinhydr1-21&ref=pd_sl_4ibn5odsi1_e).

I wanted a decent looking mic basically for video recordings. Please suggest.

Comment: From a quick search, it looks more like a [Sony Voice Recorder](https://www.amazon.com/Sony-VOICERECORDER-MICROUSB-RECORDING-WEIGHT-ICDTX650B-CE7/dp/B00TKEV9MU). Is this what you are looking for, or are you asking for a microphone suggestion?

Comment: A microphone suggestion, please. Something which looks aesthetic

Comment: Then you probably have to update your question. Do you want something portable, like in the video you linked (which is probably not  a microphone but a recorder)? Or do you want something for your desktop?